# Submit Return False, But Still Submit Form - PHP, Javascript, AJAX, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is probably going to sound backwards. I need for a form to submit return false, but still submit the form.

I have a form being pulled into a page via ajax (jquery load function), and on submit I'd like to display a graphic and some text in the same div, rather than redirect the page.

This is my submit button (codeigniter):

```
<?php $attributes = array('class' => 'button', 'onclick' => 'form_success_client(); return false;', 'name' => 'submit'); echo form_submit( $attributes, 'Save'); ?>
```

and in html:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="form_success(); return false;" class="button" value="Save" name="submit">
```

and the javascript function which loads the success message:

```
 function form_success_client() { // form success
    $('.contentarea').load("/mm/index.php/site/form_success_client/");
 }
```

That all works fine, but unsurprisngly it doesn't submit the form. I know that the proper way to do this, is to pass the form submission over to jquery, but I'm not sure how to do that. Could do with a quick fix if possible (until I have time to sort a better solution out), however all suggestions appreciated.

Thanks!

ANSWER:

This is what worked for me, just a slight edit of Maggie's answer:

```
function form_success_client(obj) {
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: $(obj).attr('action'),
       data: $(obj).serialize(),
       success: function(msg){
         $('.contentarea').load("/mm/index.php/site/form_success_client/");
       }
     });
     return false;
}
```

Note the $() wrapping obj on url and data.

Comment: what is that return false do? What ever result it will  be called always . is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bind your JS onclick-event to the form (not the button) like this
`'onclick' => 'form_success_client(this); return false;'`

and change your function to

```
function form_success_client(obj) {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: obj.attr("action"),
       data: obj.serialize(),
       success: function(msg){
         $('.contentarea').load("/mm/index.php/site/form_success_client/");
       }
     });
}
```

***untested***

Comment: Hi @maggie, sorry for the delay. This response looks good, but I'm getting an error with the obj.attr and obj.serialize - 'obj.attr is not a function' in firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution. I'm sticking to your code

```
<input type="submit" onclick="form_success_client(this); return false;" class="button" value="Save" name="submit">

function form_success_client( i ) {
   formData = $(i).parents('form').serialize();
   $.post( "/mm/index.php/site/form_success_client/", formData, function(loaded) { $('.contentarea').append(loaded) }, 'html' );
}
```

EDIT: And yes, as maggie said, you should bind `form_success_client(this); return false;` like that

```
<form onsubmit="form_success_client(this); return false;">
```

not to the button

Comment: I believe if you are attaching the event to the form (as is probably best) that when you do the .parents('form') you'll be doing that on teh form and get nothing back. That's just running it through my in head js engine though so I may be wrong. Just a comment really that you need to add a bit more to your edit. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery .post , .get or .ajax

based on SUCCESS or returned data you can submit the form

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/